# Uso no pronominal del verbo "volver" con el sentido de "hacer adquirir una nueva cualidad a algo"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

> "El hierro se vuelve más resistente al ser aleado con carbono."

Con este sentido,  ¿también se puede usar el verbo "volver" en forma no pronominal? Por ejemplo:

> "Podemos volver más resistente el hierro aleándolo con carbono."/"Podemos volver el hierro más resistente aleándolo con carbono."

Si es el caso,  ¿cuál de esas dos frases os resulta más correcta?  ¿La en que he colocado el sustantivo "hierro" antes del adjetivo "resistente" o la otra?

Answer (score 1):

Sí, se puede usar *volver* en el sentido de “transformar en” como transitivo, no pronominal. El DLE lo contempla en la definición 7 de *[volver](https://dle.rae.es/volver?m=form)*:

> 7. tr. Hacer que se mude o trueque alguien o algo de un estado o aspecto en otro. U. m. c. prnl. *Volverse blanco, tonto.*

El DLE aclara: “Úsase más como pronominal”. Es bastante poco frecuente verlo de esta otra manera. A mí personalmente me suena bien pero algo arcaico, y tuve que consultarlo con el diccionario para saber si era correcto.

Considerando

1. “volver más resistente el hierro”
2. “volver el hierro más resistente”

creo que (1) suena mejor que (2) porque

- la versión (1) mantiene unidos el verbo y su complemento adjetival, y esta unión es la que permite al oyente identificar este significado particular de “volver”;
- en la versión (2) se produce una *garden-path phrase*: al leerla secuencialmente uno tiende a identificar “el hierro más resistente” como una frase nominal con un superlativo y sólo se da cuenta de su error más tarde, cuando después no viene el complemento esperado para “volver” (en el sentido de “devolver, retornar”).